# Redux Action with For loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

TLDR : Weird Mutations. Solved with re-assigning variables. But not the most efficient...

---

**PREFACE**

I have a component called `Feed` connected to redux

```js
export class Feed extends Component {

  bookmark = (id) => {
    this.props.bookmarkItem(id).then(s=>{
      this.props.updateFeed(this.props.feed, this.props.bookmarks);
    }); //redux action with redux-thunk
  }

  render(){
      //renders card items with a bookmark button on each card
      //onPress button call this.bookmark(item.id)  
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  feed: state.app.feed,
  bookmarks: state.app.bookmarks
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { bookmarkItem, updateFeed })(Feed)
```

On pressing a button on the card,  a `this.bookmark()` function is called and an action `this.props.bookmarkItem(id)` is called.

The `bookmarkItem` redux action looks like this.

```js
export const bookmarkItem = (item_id) => async dispatch => {
    try {

        let r = await axios.post(`/bookmark`); //api call

        let { bookmarks } = r; //get updated bookmarked items from api

        dispatch({
            type: cons.UPDATE_BOOKMARKED,
            payload: { bookmarked }
        });

        return true;
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

Redux state looks like this

```js
let app = {
  feed: [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}],
  bookmarks:[{id:1}, {id:2}]
}
```

**AIM**

Now I gotta update the `feed` array in Redux State with property `isBookmarked` for that each item in feed.

(So that we can display that item is already bookmarked or not)

So for that I am calling another `updateFeed()` redux action

```js
export const updateFeed = (feed, bookmarks) => dispatch => {

  console.log('checkpoint 1', feed); //CHECKPOINT 1

  for (let i = 0; i < feed.length; i++) {
    if (bookmarks.length == 0) {
      feed[i].isBookmarked = false; //mark item as NOT bookmarked
    } else {
      //check all bookmarks
      for (let p = 0; p < bookmarks.length; p++) {
        //if bookmark exists, set item in feed as isBookmarked:true
        if (bookmarks[p].id === feed[i].id)
          feed[i].isBookmarked = true; //mark item as bookmarked
      }
    }
  }

  dispatch({
    type: cons.UPDATE_FEED,
    payload: {
      feed
    }
  });
};
```

**PROBLEM**

So there are a few problems I'm facing here:

1. At `CHECKPOINT 1` the feed object logs a mutated feed with `isBookmarked` property in Google Chrome Console, even before the loop is started.
2. The payload that goes at `UPDATE_FEED` action is the with `isBookmarked` property, but the re-render of the feed never takes place.

**HACKY WORKAROUND**

Assigning `feed` to a new variable `t` in `UPDATE_FEED` action correctly mutates and then sends in the dispatch call.

But I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it.

```js
export const updateFeed = (feed, bookmarks) => dispatch => {

  let t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(feed));

  console.log('checkpoint 1', feed); //CHECKPOINT 1

  for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    if (bookmarks.length == 0) {
      t[i].isBookmarked = false; //mark item as NOT bookmarked
    } else {
      //check all bookmarks
      for (let p = 0; p < bookmarks.length; p++) {
        //if bookmark exists, set item in feed as isBookmarked:true
        if (bookmarks[p].id === t[i].id)
          t[i].isBookmarked = true; //mark item as isBookmarked
      }
    }
  }

  dispatch({
    type: cons.UPDATE_FEED,
    payload: {
      feed : t //THIS WORKS CORRECTLY
    }
  });
};
```

Is waiting until that for loop is finished asynchronously a better way to do it ?

**EXTRAS**

Reducer looks like this. Pretty simple, only updates with new values, all cases handled by single switch method.

```js
const initialState = {
    feed: [],
    bookmarks:[]
}


const app = (state = initialState, action) => {

    console.log('appReducer', action, JSON.stringify(state));

    switch (action.type) {
        case cons.UPDATE_BOOKMARKS:
        case cons.UPDATE_FEED:
            {
                state = {
                    ...state,
                    ...action.payload,
                }
                break;
            }

    }

    return state;
}

export default app;
```

Comment: Could you please add reducers for the same

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Added Reducer.

Answer (score 0):

> Assigning feed to a new variable t in UPDATE_FEED action correctly mutates

It simply means,your reducers not creating new state object.Its just mutate the state in place.

It uses `===` to check state update in state tree.

`...action.payload` it coping the same reference for feed object and nested element  as it is in the new state.So,there is no state update.

Change `cons.UPDATE_FEED` like this.

```
state = {
           ...state,
           ...action.payload.feed,
         }
```

Comment: You're right. But for some reason the object that i'm logging in reducer shows an already updated `state` with mutated `feed` even before it has been updated...

Comment: Did you put debugger n checked it?Please install chrome redux dev tool.It will help you to track state update sequence